# Deep Copy diagrams from enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

Hi Its possible to **deep copy** a diagram manually in EA . But is it possible to do it programmatically from an addin . 
somethind like

> `diagram.cop()` or `diagram.duplicate()` ? .

Or any other ways to copy an entire diagram with its diagram objects and diagram links .

Answer (score 0):

There is no genuine method for that. You have to use the "manual" tedious way by iterating `DiagramObjects` and creating them new in the second diagram.

I thought of using `EaPackage.Clone` to create a full copy of the package that contains the diagram and the removing the unneeded stuff. But unfortunately the diagram points to the cloned elements.

**Solution**

Now that I write that: You can move the diagram to a temporary package. Now you use `EaPackage.Clone` and voila you have an exact copy of the diagram. Move the original diagram back to where it came from and delete the temp package.

Comment: this will work if ll the diagram objects are under the same package . If the diagram contains objects from different package it wont work .

Comment: I found a solution. Tricky as always when dealing with EA :-/ The Sparxians are not very clever when it comes to their API. There could be clone operations for everything.